# What shall be the best optimized preg pattern for this data?? Regular Expression help needed

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

I need help with php preg pattern to extract contents from the following data :

```
<div class="box">
<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjkswdkjbg0B;detail=person;id=937382/me">
<b>Smith, Johnny</b>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjkswdkjbg0B/http%3aservice.myxyz.net/ch/cgi/g.fcgi/me/new?CUSTOMERNO=836327973&amp;t=i373u.1310541179.a1ecb28b&amp;TO=smithjohnny@gmail.com">smithjohnny@gmail.com</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjkswdkjbg0B;edit=person;id=937382/me"><img src="/;m=is;f=gif89a;h=18;k=sdakjdk12eksack;w=18/it%3amfitmcsfe19/DiEDzr48XbZcjfyGLMKnzw.gif" alt="" width="18" height="18">
</a>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjkswdkjbg0B;delete=person;id=937382/me">
<img src="/;m=is;f=gif89a;h=18;k=Dk3k-kVox-ads9Lopt-yBQ;w=18/it%3amfitmcsfe19/tHJTBPhousrElDf1x5aPvA.gif" alt="" width="18" height="18">
</a>
</div>

<div class="fitMlModuleLinec8fe6cf8">&nbsp;</div>

<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjk4jkedkds8g0B;detail=person;id=327843287/me"></a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjk4jkedkds8g0B/http%3aservice.myxyz.net/ch/cgi/g.fcgi/me/new?CUSTOMERNO=98324826438&amp;t=de13929382.1310541179.a1ecb28b&amp;TO=iamtesting@gmail.com">iamtesting@gmail.com</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjk4jkedkds8g0B;edit=person;id=327843287/me">
<img src="/;m=is;f=gif89a;h=18;k=cBoj9wS5Yp5345435EREg;w=18/it%3amfitmcsfe19/DiEDzr48XbZcjfyGLMKnzw.gif" alt="" width="18" height="18"></a> | 
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGFjk4jkedkds8g0B;delete=person;id=327843287/me">
<img src="/;m=is;f=gif89a;h=18;k=Dk3k-kVox-ads9Lopt-yBQ;w=18/it%3amfitmcsfe19/tHJTBPhousrElDf1x5aPvA.gif" alt="" width="18" height="18"></a>
</div>

<div class="fitMlModuleLinec8fe6cf8">&nbsp;</div>

<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGsndqw21g0B;detail=person;id=83467836/me">
<b>Parker</b>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGsndqw21g0B;edit=person;id=83467836/me">
<img src="/;m=is;f=gif89a;h=18;k=cBodejksa23KNKvUEREg;w=18/it%3amfitmcsfe19/DiEDzr48XbZcjfyGLMKnzw.gif" alt="" width="18" height="18"></a> | 
<a href="/;s=-w3NKGF6hSNhymOcg6uWbg0B;delete=person;id=83467836/me">
<img src="/;m=is;f=gif89a;h=18;k=Dk3k-kVox-ads9Lopt-yBQ;w=18/it%3amfitmcsfe19/tHJTBPhousrElDf1x5aPvA.gif" alt="" width="18" height="18"></a>
</div>

<div class="fitMlModuleLinec8fe6cf8">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The above data looks like this : 
[image: http://i56.tinypic.com/t867ih.jpg]

Following are the conditions :

- I want to extract email addresses.
- If email address is found then check for name.. if name found then
  fetch name of the person for that email address.
- If name is found and no email address for that person is specified
  then discard the data.

The output array should look like :

```
Array(
[email#1]= array([name]='name'),
[email#2]= array([name]='name')
.
.
[email#n]= array([name]='name')   
)
```

The result from above data should look like :

```
Array(
[smithjohnny@gmail.com]= array([name]='Smith, Johnny'),
[iamtesting@gmail.com]= array([name]='')
)
```

Kindly suggest me the highest optimized `preg_match` for above problem.

Comment: You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions.  They are not up to the task.  As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken.  See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about the quality of your data, but you could

```
preg_match("/<a href=\".+?\">([^<]+)@([^<]+)</a>", "smithjonny@gmail.com", $matches);
// $matches[1]='smithjonny'
// $matches[2]='gmail.com'
```

This is a bit crude but if you can guarantee the `href` doesn't contain `"` (which should be excaped to `&quot;`) then it will extract the e-mail.

Comment: Nop brother.. thanks for your answer but its not the solution for my question.. It would require more operations to join that email and then getting name field (if present) for that entry..